# How do I convert an ASCII char into a decimal number?

Tags: c#

How do I convert an ASCII char into a decimal number?

The decimal number for 'a' is 97 (ASCII Table).  This code results in uiValue = -1.

```
char cValue = 'a';
int uiValue = (int)Char.GetNumericValue(cValue);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use:

```
int uiValue = (int) cValue;
```

or

```
int uiValue = cValue;
```

*( since a `char` value can be stored in `int` due to widening scope, `char` is 16 bit, `int` is 32 bit)*

[`Char.GetNumericValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.getnumericvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is useful when you are trying to convert an actual digit in character to int value. For example if your have `'9'` stored in your character variable then you will get `9` digit in your `int` variable.